# getimagesize() not working for image upload

Tags: php, getimagesize

My attempt at getting the size of a newly uploaded image appears not to be working properly.

```
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['image_field']);

echo 'width:'.$w;
```

outputs:

```
width:
```

How is this possible? I know for a fact the image (.jpg) is uploading fine because it's now on my server.

Comment: the uploaded file is stored into $_FILES[..][**tmp_name**] before you use move_uploaded_file() or equal functions

Comment: @donald123 not sure I understand what you mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES["image_field"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Comment: $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; will contain the temporary file name of the file on the server. This is just a placeholder on your server until you process the file.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to upload file then pass the uploaded location

> getimagesize("location_of_file/".$file_name);

OR

> getimagesize($path['path'].'/'.$_POST['name']);

OR

> $file_name=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
>   getimagesize($target_dir.'/'.$file_name);

OR

> $file_tmp=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']; list($width, $height) =
>   getimagesize($file_tmp);
>        $file_width=$width;
>        $file_height=$height;